# Ordering the items in the array

Tags: java, android, arrays

Hi am trying to draw polygons on the map depending on the shortest distance.

i have created the array list called **distancearray**.

but i want to create a new array list called **shortdistance**, this array list must have the same values in the distancearray but it must be shorted in assending order depending on the distance.

can any one help me to create this **shortdistance** array. Thank you.

```
String array[][]=dbhand.collecting(getIntent().getExtras().getString("temple_type"), Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().getString("notemples")));

for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){                
    displaymarkers(Double.parseDouble(array[i][0]), Double.parseDouble(array[i][1]), array[i][2]);
}

for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    double Distance = calculate_distance(SEATTLE_LAT, SEATTLE_LNG, Double.parseDouble(array[i][0]), Double.parseDouble(array[i][1]));

    double[][] distancearray = new double[array.length][3];

    distancearray[i][0]=Double.parseDouble(array[i][0]);
    distancearray[i][1]=Double.parseDouble(array[i][1]);
    distancearray[i][2]=Distance;

}

double [][] shortdistance = new double [array.length][3];
```

Draw Polygon Function

```
private void drawpolygon(String array[][]) {

    int lengh = array.length;
    if(lengh==2){
        mMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
        //.add(new LatLng(9.662502, 80.010239), new LatLng(9.670931, 80.013201), new LatLng(9.663216, 80.01333))
        .add(new LatLng(9.6632139, 80.0133258))
        .add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(array[0][0]), Double.parseDouble(array[0][1])))
        .add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(array[1][0]), Double.parseDouble(array[1][1])))
       .fillColor(Color.GRAY));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have difficulty sorting your arrays as-is because you currently store your data in parallel arrays:

```
        distancearray[i][0]=Double.parseDouble(array[i][0]);
        distancearray[i][1]=Double.parseDouble(array[i][2]);
        distancearray[i][3]=Distance;
```

You can sort `distancearray[n]` but that will give you nonsense results. Instead what you should do is create a small class that implements [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) (comparing based on distance) that holds your three values, then work with an array of those classes:

```
class DistanceInfo implements Comparable<DistanceInfo> {
    public double a;
    public double b;
    public double distance;
    public DistanceInfo (double a, double b, double distance) {
        this.a = a; 
        this.b = b;
        this.distance = distance;
    }
    @Override public int compareTo (DistanceInfo d) { 
        return Double.compare(distance, d.distance);
    }
}

// then:
DistanceInfo[] distancearray = new DistanceInfo[array.length];

// and you can load it using the constructor:
for (int i = 0; i < array.length) {
    double a = Double.parseDouble(array[i][0]);
    double b = Double.parseDouble(array[i][1]);
    distancearray[i] = new DistanceInfo(a, b, Distance);
}
```

(The fields can be made `final` if you wish to specify that they cannot be modified after construction.)

Now, [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) will sort `distancearray` based on distance:

```
Arrays.sort(distancearray, null);
```

You could also use an [`ArrayList<DistanceInfo>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead, the idea is the same except you sort with [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29).

In general, for this reason (among others) it is usually better to use a class to store all information about an object as opposed to parallel arrays.

---

As an aside, you may want to consider using this class for `array` as well, it will simplify your code a bit (you can modify `displaymarkers` to take a `DistanceInfo`, and you can also avoid parsing the same double more than once).

Comment: Thank you Jason. i have edited the question. i want to pass the array to the `drawpolygon(distancearray);` function.i have added the drawpolygon function to the question can you please tell me how can i pass the distancearray to drawpolygon function.

Comment: @user3234352 Passing parameters to functions is pretty basic Java. You need to read through the official tutorial on [Passing Information to Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html).

Answer (score 4):

Just call `Arrays.sort()` against your array and specify a comparator that looks at the distance.

Comment: `Arrays.sort()` will not work for this because he is using parallel arrays (and in the wrong order to boot -- `array[object_index][field_index]`).